# Download .xls file via POST

Tags: angularjs, http, post, download

I am using AngularJS and in POST request download file .xls

```
this.$http.post('/api/rept/detc/xls', params).then((response) => {                  
    let blob = new Blob([response], { 
        type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" 
    }),
    objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    window.open(objectUrl);
})
```

But then download file without format with name (in this format: c65c45f8-e6a3-458d-xxxx-43c5fcxxxxx).
How can I download without FileSave package?

Comment: From what I understood, you want to show the Save as dialog to save the file, or..?

Comment: yes, dialog or save automatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar approach that worked for me:

```
this.$http.post('/api/rept/detc/xls', params).then((response) => {                  
    let blob = new Blob([response]);
    let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'filename_here';
    a.target = '_blank';
    a.click();
})
```